# 301 Redirect not working correctly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-alias, ghost

I need to redirect a Blog on a subdomain running on [Ghost](https://ghost.org/) and all its posts to a new location. The currently sits in `http://blog.example.com` and needs to be redirected to `http://example.com/blog/`

For the original Ghost blog, Apache was used as a proxy, because Ghost is running on node.js. For that reason, I cannot simply use a `.htaccess` in the root folder of the Ghost installation.

I used a [301 redirection generator](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/redirect-generator.htm) to set all required redirects and then placed the code directly in `etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`, like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName blog.example.com

  Redirect 301 / http://example.com/blog/
  Redirect 301 /post-title-1/ http://example.com/blog/post-title-1.html
  Redirect 301 /post-title-2/ http://example.com/blog/post-title-2.html
  Redirect 301 /post-title-3/ http://example.com/blog/post-title-3.html

</VirtualHost>
```

I then restarted the server.

`http://blog.example.com` is now correctly redirecting to `http://example.com/blog/`, but the individual posts are pointed to the wrong location. Instead of applying the new location, e.g. `post-title-1.html`, they are pointed to `http://example.com/blog/post-title-1/`, which logically throws a 404 error.

Would appreciate your advive, how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have rules in wrong order i.e **most generic catch-all rule** is your first rule and taking precedence over rest of the rules.

Use:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName blog.example.com

  Redirect 301 /post-title-1/ http://example.com/blog/post-title-1.html
  Redirect 301 /post-title-2/ http://example.com/blog/post-title-2.html
  Redirect 301 /post-title-3/ http://example.com/blog/post-title-3.html
  Redirect 301 / http://example.com/blog/

</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: You're right, I was not aware that the rules apply in a certain order. Now it works as intended.